# Laravel Vue Inertia CRUD

Tags: laravel, vue.js, crud, inertiajs

So I'm making a CRUD application using Laravel, Vue, and Inertia. I have successfully made the Create feature, but I am facing a problem in the Edit.

This is my store and update method in the controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'brand' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'name' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);
        $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();
        $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
        Product::create([
            'brand' => $request->brand,
            'name' => $request->name,
            'image' => $imageName,
        ]);
        sleep(1);
        return redirect()->route('products.index')->with('message', 'Product Successfully Added');
    }
```

```
public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'brand' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'name' => 'required',
            'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);
        $data = [
            'brand' => $request->brand,
            'name' => $request->name,
        ];
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $request->validate([
                'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
            ]);

            $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();
            $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
            if ($product->image) {
                $oldImagePath = public_path('images').'/'.$product->image;
                if (file_exists($oldImagePath)) {
                    unlink($oldImagePath);
                }
            }
            $data['image'] = $imageName;
        }
        $product->update($data);
        return redirect()->route('products.index')->with('message', 'Product Successfully Updated');
    }
```

And this is my script in the view file

```
const props = defineProps({
    product: {
        type: Object,
        default: () => ({}),
    },
});

const form = useForm({
    brand: props.product.brand,
    name: props.product.name,
    image: null,
});

const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    form.image = event.target.files[0];
};

const submit = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('brand', form.brand);
    formData.append('name', form.name);
    if (form.image) {
        formData.append('image', form.image);
    }
    form.put(route("products.update", props.product.id), formData);
};
```

While using this, it just gives me a flash of 409 error, and then refreshing the page like nothing happens.

I have tried to use patch and post, but still doesnt work.
This is my route

```
Route::resource('products',ProductController::class);
```

What's the problem here ?